# How do I interpret my validation and training loss curve if there is a large difference between the two which closes in sharply

Tags: neural-networks, optimization, conv-neural-network, convergence, loss-functions

my CNN is meant to classify an image as one out of around 30 categories. I am training on 6400 samples using a batch size of 128. I am using Keras/ Tensorflow Architecture is Conv + Batch Normalization + Convo + Batch Normalization + MaxPooling2D repeated 4 times.
Using an ADAM optimizer gives me following loss curves, orange is validation blue is training

[image: ADAM optimizer]

There is a huge gap between validation and training loss which closes in eventually. I then tried an SGD optimizer

[image: SGD optimizer]

Which looked better but I still didn’t understand why training set is able to learn so quickly and validation loss only decreases after awhile. I thought maybe its because my learning rate is too large, causing the training loss to plunge initially. I tried reducing learning rate.

[image: SGD with smaller learning rate 0.005]

But doesn't change much. I thought maybe its due to initial overfitting and that I am “lucky” to have the validation loss eventually find its way lower, so I tried adding dropouts to my model

[image: Dropout doesn't really help either]

I'm still getting the same issue. I also tried changing the momentum from 0.5 to 0.9

[image: higher momentum at 0.9]

What is causing the shape of my loss curve to be like that and how do I tweak it so validation loss drops quicker in sync? I don’t understand why there is a large gap between the two which only closes in after a few epochs.

I'm reluctant to increase my data-set since I've seen other similar projects being done with similar size data. Input image pixels have already been standardized to between 0-1

Edit: I'm posting my architecture below just for more info if it helps, hope someone takes a look cause to me its a real head-scratcher. Using Python, keras

```
feeder_input = Input(shape=(50, 55, 3))

layer_1_CovNet = Convolution2D(64, (3, 3), activation="relu", padding="same")(feeder_input)
layer_1_CovNet = BatchNormalization()(layer_1_CovNet)
layer_2_CovNet = Convolution2D(64, (3, 3), activation="relu", padding="same")(layer_1_CovNet)
layer_2_CovNet = BatchNormalization()(layer_2_CovNet)
layer_3_CovNetPl = MaxPooling2D()(layer_2_CovNet)

layer_4_CovNet = Convolution2D(128, (3, 3), activation="relu", padding="same")(layer_3_CovNetPl)
layer_4_CovNet = BatchNormalization()(layer_4_CovNet)
layer_5_CovNet = Convolution2D(128, (3, 3), activation="relu", padding="same")(layer_4_CovNet)
layer_5_CovNet = BatchNormalization()(layer_5_CovNet)
layer_6_CovNetPl = MaxPooling2D()(layer_5_CovNet)

layer_7_CovNet = Convolution2D(256, (3, 3), activation="relu", padding="same")(layer_6_CovNetPl)
layer_7_CovNet = BatchNormalization()(layer_7_CovNet)
layer_8_CovNet = Convolution2D(256, (3, 3), activation="relu", padding="same")(layer_7_CovNet)
layer_8_CovNet = BatchNormalization()(layer_8_CovNet)
layer_9_CovNetPl = MaxPooling2D()(layer_8_CovNet)

layer_10_CovNet = Convolution2D(512, (3, 3), activation="relu", padding="same")(layer_9_CovNetPl)
layer_10_CovNet = BatchNormalization()(layer_10_CovNet)
layer_11_CovNet = Convolution2D(512, (3, 3), activation="relu", padding="same")(layer_10_CovNet)
layer_11_CovNet = BatchNormalization()(layer_11_CovNet)
layer_12_CovNetPl = MaxPooling2D()(layer_11_CovNet)

ConvNetFlatten = Flatten()(layer_12_CovNetPl)

encoder_dense1 = Dense(512, activation='relu', name='encoder_dense1')
encoder_dense1_output = encoder_dense1(ConvNetFlatten)

totext_dense1 = Dense(len(char_dict), activation='softmax', name='totext_dense1')
totext_output1 = totext_dense1(encoder_dense1_output)

model_train = Model(feeder_input, totext_output1)
```

Comment: Interesting question. Please add what is on the axes.

Comment: @Jim thanks for taking a look jim. X axis is number of epochs, Y axis is loss. Again the confusion is mainly why the training loss goes down so sharply and validation loss takes so long. The validation loss of the SGD optimization looks fine by itself, but again baffled why training loss is able to drop to <1 so quickly compared to validation. Is it cause of weight initialization? I feel like someone with more experience should be able to recognize and diagnose the problem quite easily

Comment: When I look at the graphs, they raise two main questions: **1)** How can the validation loss decrease and then increase again? **1.1)** This behavior is present in some curves -- why? **2)** What explains the sharp disparity between training loss and validation loss in all graphs?

Comment: I'm curious to see this run with say, 50 - 100 epochs. Will it overfit?

Comment: yea it over fits around 20 epochs. The problem in the end was just due to data samples not being enough but it think there might be some other reasons in there as well thats not immediately or obviously clear

Answer (score 1):

Validation loss is indeed expected to decrease as the model learns and increase later as the model begins to overfit on the training set. One reason why your training and validation set behaves so different could be that they are indeed partitioned differently and the base distributions of the two are different. Did you shuffle before partitioning? If the validation set has too few samples, naturally, its behaviour may be erratic.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried lowering the learning rate of SGD to 0.001? It seems like the training loss decays too fast (due to a potentially high learning rate) and that potentially explains the divergence of the training and validation loss.